# How to adjust android button text at centre without padding?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I searched for the solution. It can be done with paddingLeft and paddingRight set to equal values. However, the problem with this is it doesn't work well for different screens. Here is my button code.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/sign_in_orange"
    android:background="@drawable/orange_button"
    android:text="Continue"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
    android:minHeight="35dp"
   />
```

The orange_button drawable is just used to attribute round edges to the button. My ultimate goal is to have a button with text centered and positioning almost same in different screens. Note that I have used linear layout in the parent xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
            android:gravity="center"
```

Comment: not possible, gravity property aligns inner objects, layout_gravity aligns whole object. See this, https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/14/how-to-position-views-properly-in-layouts/

Comment: Works, thanks! I was applying layout_gravity accidently before,

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:textAlignment="center"`.

Comment: is there anything else in your code working with that view ? Because in my multiple devices it work fines.